# Flashing CM 11, I get `set_metadata_recursive: some changes failed`:

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery

ClockworkMod Recovery v6.0.2.3 gives me the folling error when I try to update my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (GT-P5113) to Cyanogenmod 11:

```
Restarting adbd...
Finding update package...
Opening update package...
Installing update...
set_metadata_recursive: some changes failed
E:Error in /tmp/update.zip
(status 7)
Installation aborted.
```

Being desperate I tried the same thing with [Team Win Recovery Project (TWRP)](http://techerrata.com/browse/twrp2/p5110) v2.6.3.0 -- also the latest for my platofrm,

```
Checking for MD5 file...
Skipping MD5 check: no MD5 file file found.
set_metadata_recursive: some changes filed
E:Error: executing updater binary in zip '/data/media/0/sideload.zip'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In short, if you want to flash KitKat Android 4.4, you'll have to upgrade to a version of CWM greater than v6.0.4.5. Or, use an alternate bootloader. For the Galaxy Tab 2 GT-P5113 or GT-p5110 [you can find the instructions here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/62986/7425).

Comment: Any references or links about why does this happen, please?

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez I provided an explanation on the link to further instructions. This is an error message (if you try first without knowing), the other question is a tutorial-answer with more details.

Answer (score 7):

A zip package that contains a firmware update always includes two files in `META-INF/com/google/android`: `updater-script` and `update-binary`. `updater-script` is a text file containing commands required to install the update. `update-binary` translates the commands into binary code.

In Android 4.4 KitKat, Google has changed the interface that `updater-script` uses for setting up permissions. The previously used `set_perm` method was deprecated and replaced by `set_metadata`. This causes old versions of custom recovery software to fail with Android 4.4 packages (e.g. CyanogenMod 11) and display the error message "set_metadata_recursive: some changes failed".

The best solution is to update the custom recovery software. I haven't found a new enough version of ClockworkMod compiled for my device, but I have found the newest version of TWRP to work.

Second option is to fix the `updater-script` by replacing any `set_metadata` and `set_metadata_recursive` calls with the old syntax, i.e. `set_perm` and `set_perm_recursive`. I haven't done this so I'm not sure how easy this would be.

Third option is to replace the `update-binary` with a patched one created by XDA member daniel_hk:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2532300
. I have done this and it worked fine, but the binary is compiled for ARMv7 and won't work in any other architecture.

Comment: Replacing the `update-binary` worked on my **Oppo Find 5** for both the ROM and gapps. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed: upgrading TWRP from 2.6.3 to 2.8 did the trick for me. After that the set_metadata_recursive error when flashing new ROMs disappeared. Thanks a lot for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [jmullee's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/86964/44325), made by comparison of cm-10.1.3 and cm-11 updater-script. After this replacement, I successfully flashed `cm-11-20141110-NIGHTLY-n7000.zip` with recovery 5 (built-in in ICS speedmod kernel).

```
set_metadata => set_perm
set_metadata_recursive => set_perm_recursive

sed -i "s|set_metadata(\(\"[^\"]*\"\), \"uid\", \([0-9]*\), \"gid\", \([0-9]*\), \"mode\", \([0-9]*\).*);|set_perm(\2, \3, \4, \1);|" updater-script
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that modifiying the \META-INF\com\google\android\updater-script file in a text editor, and replacing all the set_metadata_recursive by its old version set_param_recursive (the signature of the functions are relatively equivalent), after that you have to re-zip the pack and sign the file.
For replacing and figure it out how to do it: search in google "replace set_metadata_recursive by set_param_recursive phyton" somebody has created a phyton script but if you understand the functions signatures you can doit manually.
- then repack and sign the zip.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote this search/replace pattern that munges the new format into the old, and it worked for me:

```
$ sed -i "s|set_metadata_recursive(\\(\"[^\"]\*\"\\), \"uid\", \\([0-9]\*\\), \"gid\", \\([0-9]\*\\), \"dmode\", \\([0-9]\*\\), \"fmode\", \\([0-9]\*\\),.*);|set_perm_recursive(\2, \3, \4, \5, \1);|" META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script
```

In the end the google-play app wouldn't install either, so I bit the bullet and flashed an updated recovery (`recovery-clockwork-6.0.4.6-i9300.img` with heimdal) and was then able to flash an unmodified CM11. Aside, Google Play had errors until I disabled 3G (forcing IPv4 over WiFi), it seems there were (temporary?) issues connecting to Play Servers via IPv6.

Comment: A bit more information would be useful. Did you get this from a forum? Or did you write it yourself? In either case, `random piece of code` isn't all that helpful without some comments (especially in the case of regular expressions).

Comment: ok sorry -



it's just a search/replace pattern I wrote that munges the new format into the old.



In the end the google-play app wouldn't install either, so I bit the bullet and flashed an updated recovery (recovery-clockwork-6.0.4.6-i9300.img, with heimdal ) and was then able to flash an unmodified cm11.



Aside, google play had errors until I disabled 3G (forcing IPv4 over wifi), it seems there were (temporary?) issues connecting to play servers via IPv6

Answer (score -1):

ERROR STATUS 7 is because  of  you will have to upgrade CWM version to greater than or equal to the version CWM  v 6.0.4.4  to install kitkat and lollipop on samsung Galaxy Tab 2 GT-P5113 or GT-p5110

Comment: That may be true, but can you back your claim with source(s)?

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you enable "USB Debugging" under "Developer options" on your rooted phone. That worked for me.

Comment: What do developer options have to do with recovery? When booted into CWM/TWRP, those play no role at all. Especially not for flashing ROMs.

Comment: They are completely unrelated.

Comment: I believe this answer is referring to the "USB Debugging" setting, which on some devices/versions can set a flag in nvram that is indeed readable from Recovery.