# How do I install Cyanogenmod 11 on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (GT-P5113)?

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1, twrp, cyanogenmod

I'd like to install Cyanogenmod 11 on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (GT-P5113), is this currently possible? I see the Rom shows up in Cyanogenmod's Updater.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update

Previously it wasn't possible.

> In short, the previously used set_perms method was deprecated and replaced by set_metadata. Unfortunately, most of available recoveries didn’t allow users to flash these packages properly, and this has resulted in the following error message: set_metadata_recursive: some changes failed

But now all major recoveries support `set_metadata_recursive`. Just use a version of [TWRP newer than 2.7.0](https://twrp.me/)

What I did was boot into *Download Mode*:

1. Shut down the tablet.
2. Unplug the USB.
3. Hold Volume Up and Power.
4. Let go of both after it boots and you see it is in Download Mode.
5. Plug in USB.

Flash it into the RECOVERY partition,

```
heimdall flash --RECOVERY twrp-3.1.1-0-whatever.img --no-reboot
```

Now when you boot into Recovery Mode and you're in TWRP you'll see the option to flash the CM11 .zip, or `adb sideload` it, which is what I did.

Comment: The link to "PhilZ-NON-Touch-Recovery_6_(Advanced-CWM).tar.md5" is dead

Comment: @naXa updated now