# Should I install higher CWM on old device?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, clockworkmod-recovery, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I am [updating my Galaxy S3 Mini with Android 5](http://www.android.gs/update-galaxy-s3-mini-with-android-5-0-lollipop-firmware/). Here is my steps:

1. Copy the Lollipop firmware and Google apps package downloaded in the page above into phone (not sd card).
2. Because I meet the `fail to verify whole-file signature` error, I need to install ClockworkMod Recovery. I used Odin 3.10. The name of the recovery file is `recovery-clockwork-touch-6.0.2.7-golden.tar.md5`. I downloaded it from [the #4 comment in this page](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2232278). However when I checked back, it gave me 404 error :-/
3. Everything seems to be ok, the Lollipop was installed successfully. Nevertheless when I installed Google apps, I got the [`set_metadata_recursive: some changes failed`](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62982/flashing-cm-11-i-get-set-metadata-recursive-some-changes-failed) error. The best answer suggested me to install a higher version of CWM, however when I go to the [ROM Manager page of ClowkworkMod website](https://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager), I see that the highest version of CWM for my device is 6.0.2.7, the version that I'm using.

So should I use the higher version of CWM, even though it's not build for my device?

---

After Matthew Read suggests me to recover, I repeat step 2. This time, I can't access the recovery mode. The phone screen keeps being black and after a while it restarts to normal mode.

Comment: Likely you can recover with Odin if you flash a bad recovery, but one that isn't tweaked for the device isn't likely to work.  Often the mount points will be messed up or it won't accept input from the hardware keys.

Comment: That 404 is a little disconcerting!  Try [the CWM image from the official site](http://download2.clockworkmod.com/recoveries/recovery-clockwork-6.0.2.7-golden.img) (or [touch version](http://download2.clockworkmod.com/recoveries/recovery-clockwork-touch-6.0.2.7-golden.img)).  You could also try [TWRP](http://teamw.in/project/twrp2/153).

Comment: All three are corrupted. However the last link leads me to [this recovery](http://get.novafusion.pl/?id=1375#). After flashing it, the phone freezes in the welcome screen (Samsung Galaxy SIII mini...) when I access to the recovery mode.

Comment: OK, at this point I would recommend that you flash the original stock ROM with Odin, whatever version it shipped with.  It's hard to say exactly what is messed up here but it's probably safest to go to a known good state.